# Matching Satellite Images to map

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm currently a little stuck with a problem, that sounds easier than it is (at least for me):

Let's say you have satellite images taken from LEO that show an approximately 1000 km wide area (the image axis of the camera is more or less perpendicular to the ground). There is no additional location data stored in the image, so no way of directly extracting the position the image was taken).

What I want to do is write a program (in python) that can find the location the image was taken from by matching it to a map of earth. this should be done automatically (more or less in real time) for the purpose of calculating the orbit of the satellite taking the images.

I've no problem calculating the orbit, once I have location data (even if it's very noisy), using a technique based on an Extended Kalman Filter.

Matching a satellite image to a map of earth by just using the image data, on the other hand.... I honestly don't even know where to start.

I know this is an incredibly unspecific question and not related to a specific problem, but maybe someone could point me in the right direction...

EDIT:
Just to give you an idea how unprocessed images from LEO look, I included a few reasonably good images taken over one orbit of earth.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Images have been taken with a NIR camera. Resolution of the images I included have been only 640x480 (by mistake!), but image resolution should be around 4k.

These images have some artifacts in them due to the fact that they where taken through a thick glass window of the ISS - so there are some reflections happening there...

Comment: You will need some form of *template matching*, based on the generation of images of the Earth in viewing conditions as close as possible to those of the satellite. The problem is made more difficult by the fact that your image sources are of a different nature. Lookup "multimodal template matching".

Comment: please [edit] your question and add some imagery of both the "needle" and "haystack", for prototyping. -- you make this problem unreasonably difficult by not allowing for any knowledge of the approximate location. if you could supply an approximate location, searching for a match near that location would be cheap. -- this can get hairy because the sat looks straight down, but the surface of earth isn't flat, so maps aren't flat either. this might require feature matching, not just something correlation-based.... general area of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval

Comment: Good point. I included some images I took last year on the ISS to give you an idea what I'm dealing with.

Comment: you could try asking on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/. you could even try to formulate this as a machine learning (deep learning) problem (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/), e.g. having the network directly infer coordinates given an input picture. that should be amenable to (semi)synthetic data, i.e. renderings of a virtual camera over random points over a globe with actual 3d/height information, textured with georeferenced sat pictures. digital elevation models and visible light imagery in usable resolutions are probably free to get.